# How to make git show to use formatting?

Tags: git, formatting

`git show --oneline 0.1` (0.1 is lightweight tag name) doesn't work for me. The feature itself is working well, but it always shows full description including diffs.

How can I make it to use formatting?

I'm using Mac OS X.

```
git version
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)
```

---

### Edit

I checked it again, and I discovered the result is printed as one-line style.
But it still includes full diff result.

```
e14b982 Downgraded to Xcode 4.2 from Xcode 4.5 DP3.
diff --git a/EonilSQLite.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj b/EonilSQLite.xcodeproj/project.pbxpro
index 54ab6bc..75e4e78 100644
--- a/EonilSQLite.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
+++ b/EonilSQLite.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
@@ -656,6 +656,7 @@
                                ARCHS = "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)";
                                GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
                                GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = Targets/iOS/Prefix.pch;
+                               MACH_O_TYPE = staticlib;
                                OTHER_LDFLAGS = "-ObjC";
                                PRODUCT_NAME = EonilSQLite;
                                SDKROOT = iphoneos;
@@ -670,6 +671,7 @@

....(more and more)
```

Comment: Typo in your command, should be `--oneline`.

Comment: @suvayu I fixed wrong typo in question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
git show --oneline 0.1
```

;-)

And for only printing the first line of the output, do

```
git show --oneline 0.1 | head -1
```

Comment: And what is the output that you get?

Comment: ok. I can reproduce that. A workaround would be `git show --oneline 0.1 | head -1`.

Comment: Oh this solved my problem. Thanks. Anyway I'm not sure this is normal behavior or not. Because I never seen any diff result on any manuals. Is it normal?

Comment: @Eonil: Don't hesitate to vote up, if the answer solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rereading your question, I think you are using the wrong command.

If you want to look at your history, `git log` is the command you want. On the other hand if you just want to look at a particular commit, your use of `git show` is correct. It will however always show the commit diff along with the message. Both commands accept the `--oneline` command line parameter. However it flag only affects the commit message formatting.